# For a stopping time does $E[(\tau \wedge t)1_A]=E[(\tau \wedge s)1_A] $ for $s \le t $ and any $A \in \mathcal F_{\tau \wedge s }$?

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

I have the following question as stated in the title:

> For a stopping time $\tau $ does $E[(\tau \wedge t)1_A]=E[(\tau \wedge s)1_A] $ for $s \le t $ and any $A \in \mathcal F_{\tau \wedge s }$?

Here $\mathcal F_{\tau \wedge s } $ is the $\sigma $-algebra of $\tau \wedge s $-past.

---

The context is that I'm trying to show that $(B^2_{\tau \wedge t } - \tau \wedge t,\mathcal F_{\tau \wedge t })$ is a martingale and the question is here is a second step in showing that $E[\tau \wedge t|\mathcal F_{\tau \wedge s} ]=\tau \wedge s$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider the case where $A=\Omega$ and $\tau$ is a constant stopping time with the value $\tau_0$. Then certainly we should not expect $\tau_0\wedge t=E[\tau\wedge t]=E[\tau\wedge s]=\tau_0\wedge s$ to hold in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\mathbb{E}[(\tau \wedge t)\mathbf{1}_A] & = \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}\left[(\tau \wedge t)\mathbf{1}_A\;|\;\mathcal F_{\tau \wedge s }\right]\Big]\quad\text{by the tower property}\\
& = \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}\left[(\tau \wedge t)\;|\;\mathcal F_{\tau \wedge s }\right]\mathbf{1}_A\Big]\quad\text{by measurability}\\
& \neq \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}\left[(\tau \wedge s)\;|\;\mathcal F_{\tau \wedge s }\right]\mathbf{1}_A\Big]\\
& = \mathbb{E}\left[(\tau \wedge s)\mathbf{1}_A\right],
\end{alignat*}
so answer seems no. Counterexample: $\tau=\infty$ almost surely.

---

If $B$ is a standard Brownian motion, then $\mathbb E\left[ B^2_{t}\right] = {t}$ and $\mathbb E\left[ B^2_{t}\;\;|\;\; \mathcal{F}_s\right] = B_s^2 + {t-s}$.

What you need to show seems
$$
\mathbb E\left[ B_{\tau\wedge t}^2 - {\tau\wedge t} \;\;|\;\; \mathcal{F}_{\tau\wedge s}\right] = B_{\tau\wedge s}^2 - {\tau\wedge s}
$$
for which you need $(B_t-B_s)\amalg\mathcal F_s$ and $(B_t-B_s)\sim B_{t-s}$.

Comment: What about if $\tau <\infty$ a.s.?

Comment: If $\tau>t$ a.s., it still doesn't work at least. But here it seems you have a BM?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realize now that I took the wrong approach. Of course I should apply the optional stopping theorem to the continous martingale $B_t-t $ and not $B_t $ and then trying to show the matringale property separately for $\tau \wedge t $.